# How to Update existing objects in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'd like to update an object in Core Data. This is my code:

```
var detailTaskModel: TaskModel!
detailTaskModel.date = dateFromDP         //update value

let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
appDelegate.saveContext()
```

I'm using a NSFetchedResultsController and Swift.

Update:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()
```

My func for loading the CoreData data:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: TaskCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as TaskCell

    let thisTask = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as TaskModel
    cell.textLabel?.text = thisTask.task
    return cell
}
```

Saving CoreData:

```
let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TaskModel", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
let task = TaskModel(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
task.task = labelText
```

Comment: whats your question? :D

Comment: How to update a CoreData object.

Comment: Great then :) I'd still try to be a bit specific.

Comment: Could you help me to get a solution for this?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27432173/3810673

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply update any property of Core data object and call save on NSManagedObjectContext. You can also check for any changes with hasChanges method.

```
 managedObject.setValue("newValue", forKey: "propertyName")
```

Update your object like above or direct call assignment and do the following

```
if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
   var error: NSError? = nil
   if moc.hasChanges {
       !moc.save(&error)
   }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your object and save method are under the same NSManagedObjectContext

Comment: I've done it on this way. Is this correct:                  `let thisTask = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(editIndexPath) as TaskModel
thisTask.date = dateFromDP              // dateFromDP = the new date
self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.save(nil)` ?

Comment: @pablo The code should work. Can you pass in the NSError object in save and check what the issue is; then I'll be able to help you more.

Comment: Ok. If I run this code, the app crashes a the next launch at this line of code:  `cell.textLabel?.text = thisTask.task` task is a label which should be load in a tableViewCell.

Comment: Well thats probably because thisTask.task is nil, print the value of thisTask.task to make sure its not nil

Comment: Yes, thisTask.task is nil after running the code above. But why and how can I solve it?

Comment: You need to check when and where you initilize thisTask.task; Maybe it doesnt have proper value. There are two possibilities 
1. thisTask might be nil
2. only thisTask.task is nil

Comment: I don't know what I've done wrong. I updated my question with the function which loads the data. Hope it helps.  P.S If I write `thisTask.task = "Some text"` before loading the data the app is not crashing. So just `thisTask.task`is nil.

Comment: @pablo Its not a big issue really, You just need to check where you assign value to thisTask. If you could share the assignment I could help you better

Comment: I updated my question again. Are these the informations you need?

Comment: Are these informations useful?

Comment: Yes, You are making and assigning a new NSManagedObject, thats why its properties will always be nil by default.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But how should I save the text in CoreData for not getting a crash?

Comment: well you can use 

if let value = labelText {
task.task = value
}

Comment: Ok. It seems to work. But if I load the saved text it's not showing up.

Comment: This simply checks if the value is not nil then continue; so as long as value is nil that code wont work. You should set some value in task and then this code should work.

Comment: Yes. The text is saved in CoreData. But I didn't get the text printed out. Is the code correct which loads the text which is saved in CoreData (task isn't nil)?

Comment: No, You need to use NSFetchRequest to get data from coredata.

Comment: How could I do this? I tried so much but nothing is working. I give up soon.

Answer (score 4):

Updating an object in CoreData is quite similar to creating a new one. 
First you have to fetch your object from CoreData using a `fetchRequest`. After that you can edit the fetched object and update it's attributes. 
After that, just save it back using the `managedObjectContext`.

Comment: I didn't get it working (still learning Swift). Could you post a few code snippets?

Comment: @pablo you may refer to this cheat sheet https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/02/18/core-data-cheat-sheet-for-swift-ios-developers/#delete-single-entity

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, works for me.

```
if let container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer{

        let context = container.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Account>(entityName: "Account")

        let name = self.txtAccount.text

        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name!)

        do {

            let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            if (results.count > 0){

                for result in results{

                    id = result.id
                    number = result.number

                }

                actualNumber = (number + 1)

                //Update the account balance
                let update = results[0]
                update.number = actualNumber

                try context.save()

                return id

            }

        }catch let error {

            print("Error....: \(error)")

        }
```

You don't have to write 'result[0] as! NSManagedObject' because you have the NSFetchRequest of type Account and the constant "update" knows that.